# requests avoid ddos protection

Tags: python, python-requests

When I am trying to access this link from: [browser](https://csgopolygon.com/scripts/_createAccount.php)

I have that reponse:

> {"success":false}

But when I'm trying to call it from lib requests, I use that code:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
h = s.get('https://csgopolygon.com/scripts/_createAccount.php')
print(h.text)
```

When I'm running code response is:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<style>

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 2s;
}

.content.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.form {
  position: relative;

}
.form > .lefCol {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.form > .rightCol {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.button {
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}

#loading {
  text-align: center;
}

#fountainTextG{
        width:420px;
        margin:auto;
}

.fountainTextG{
        color:rgb(0,0,0);
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:44px;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal;
        float:left;
        animation-name:bounce_fountainTextG;
                -o-animation-name:bounce_fountainTextG;
                -ms-animation-name:bounce_fountainTextG;
                -webkit-animation-name:bounce_fountainTextG;
                -moz-animation-name:bounce_fountainTextG;
        animation-duration:2.09s;
                -o-animation-duration:2.09s;
                -ms-animation-duration:2.09s;
                -webkit-animation-duration:2.09s;
                -moz-animation-duration:2.09s;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
                -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
                -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
                -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        animation-direction:normal;
                -o-animation-direction:normal;
                -ms-animation-direction:normal;
                -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
                -moz-animation-direction:normal;
        transform:scale(.5);
                -o-transform:scale(.5);
                -ms-transform:scale(.5);
                -webkit-transform:scale(.5);
                -moz-transform:scale(.5);
}#fountainTextG_1{
        animation-delay:0.75s;
                -o-animation-delay:0.75s;
                -ms-animation-delay:0.75s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:0.75s;
                -moz-animation-delay:0.75s;
}
#fountainTextG_2{
        animation-delay:0.9s;
                -o-animation-delay:0.9s;
                -ms-animation-delay:0.9s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:0.9s;
                -moz-animation-delay:0.9s;
}
#fountainTextG_3{
        animation-delay:1.05s;
                -o-animation-delay:1.05s;
                -ms-animation-delay:1.05s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:1.05s;
                -moz-animation-delay:1.05s;
}
#fountainTextG_4{
        animation-delay:1.2s;
                -o-animation-delay:1.2s;
                -ms-animation-delay:1.2s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:1.2s;
                -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
}
#fountainTextG_5{
        animation-delay:1.35s;
                -o-animation-delay:1.35s;
                -ms-animation-delay:1.35s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:1.35s;
                -moz-animation-delay:1.35s;
}
#fountainTextG_6{
        animation-delay:1.5s;
                -o-animation-delay:1.5s;
                -ms-animation-delay:1.5s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s;
                -moz-animation-delay:1.5s;
}
#fountainTextG_7{
        animation-delay:1.64s;
                -o-animation-delay:1.64s;
                -ms-animation-delay:1.64s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:1.64s;
                -moz-animation-delay:1.64s;
}
#fountainTextG_8{
        animation-delay:1.79s;
                -o-animation-delay:1.79s;
                -ms-animation-delay:1.79s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:1.79s;
                -moz-animation-delay:1.79s;
}
#fountainTextG_9{
        animation-delay:1.94s;
                -o-animation-delay:1.94s;
                -ms-animation-delay:1.94s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:1.94s;
                -moz-animation-delay:1.94s;
}
#fountainTextG_10{
        animation-delay:2.09s;
                -o-animation-delay:2.09s;
                -ms-animation-delay:2.09s;
                -webkit-animation-delay:2.09s;
                -moz-animation-delay:2.09s;
}




@keyframes bounce_fountainTextG{
        0%{
                transform:scale(1);
                color:rgb(0,0,0);
        }

        100%{
                transform:scale(.5);
                color:rgb(255,255,255);
        }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce_fountainTextG{
        0%{
                -o-transform:scale(1);
                color:rgb(0,0,0);
        }

        100%{
                -o-transform:scale(.5);
                color:rgb(255,255,255);
        }
}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_fountainTextG{
        0%{
                -ms-transform:scale(1);
                color:rgb(0,0,0);
        }

        100%{
                -ms-transform:scale(.5);
                color:rgb(255,255,255);
        }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_fountainTextG{
        0%{
                -webkit-transform:scale(1);
                color:rgb(0,0,0);
        }

        100%{
                -webkit-transform:scale(.5);
                color:rgb(255,255,255);
        }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_fountainTextG{
        0%{
                -moz-transform:scale(1);
                color:rgb(0,0,0);
        }

        100%{
                -moz-transform:scale(.5);
                color:rgb(255,255,255);
        }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content" id="captcha">
  <h1>Stormwall DDoS protection</h1>
  <form class="form" action="" method="POST">

    <div class="lefCol">
      <input type="hidden" name="swp_sessionKey" value="${sessionKey}">
      <br/>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="${recaptchaPublicKey}"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Go to website">
    </div>

    <div class="rightCol">
      <p>Please confirm you are not a robot.</p>
      <p>Пожалуйста, подтвердите, что Вы не робот.</p>
    </div>

  </form>
  <div class="footer"><a href="https://stormwall.pro/" target="_blank">stormwall.pro</a></div>
</div>

<div class="content" id="loading">
  <div id="fountainTextG"><div id="fountainTextG_1" class="fountainTextG">L</div><div id="fountainTextG_2" class="fountainTextG">o</div><div id="fountainTextG_3" class="fountainTextG">a</div><div id="fountainTextG_4" class="fountainTextG">d</div><div id="fountainTextG_5" class="fountainTextG">i</div><div id="fountainTextG_6" class="fountainTextG">n</div><div id="fountainTextG_7" class="fountainTextG">g</div><div id="fountainTextG_8" class="fountainTextG">.</div><div id="fountainTextG_9" class="fountainTextG">.</div><div id="fountainTextG_10" class="fountainTextG">.</div></div>
</div>

<iframe id="reportFrame" title="Report frame" type="text/html" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; display: none;">
  <h1>Automatic report form</h1>
  <form id="reportForm" action="http://reports.stormwall.pro" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="userAgent" value="python-requests/2.19.1">
    <input type="text" name="ipAddress" value="195.218.182.93">
    <input type="text" name="host" value="csgopolygon.com">
  </form>
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timer1 = setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("captcha").className = "content show";
}, 10);
const cE = "386t98trrw9mjgo1gcd4jvkk9vae?!yt7u1031qg64h3rywryo5dahsgfszhg:ka8crny2n4o26v";
const cK = 2;
const cN = "swp_token";
const cO = ";path=/;max-age=1800";
try {
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
let avd = require('./avd');
let abc = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm:?!';
let _rpct = [];
let _rRpct = {};

function gTb(abc) {
  for(let idx=0; idx<abc.length; idx++ ) {
    _rpct[idx] = abc[idx];
    _rRpct[abc[idx]] = idx;
  }
}

function csr(key, text) {
  let mIn = _rpct.length - 1;
  let rs = '';

  for(let idx=0; idx<text.length; idx++) {
    let sbl = text[idx];

    if( typeof(_rRpct[sbl]) == 'undefined' ) {
      rs = rs + sbl;
    } else {
      let nCD = _rRpct[sbl] + key;

      if( nCD > mIn ) {
        nCD = nCD - mIn - 1;
      } else if( nCD < 0 ) {
        nCD = mIn + nCD + 1;
      }

      rs = rs + _rpct[nCD];
    }
  }

  return rs;
}

function vgE(sk, text) {
  let mIn = _rpct.length - 1;
  let crK = sk;
  let rs = '';

  for(let idx=0; idx<text.length; idx++) {
    let sbr = '' + text[idx];
    rs = rs + csr(crK, sbr);
    crK = crK + 1;

    if( crK > mIn ) {
      crK = 0;
    }
  }

  return rs;
}

function vgD(sk, text) {
  let mIn = _rpct.length - 1;
  let crK = sk;
  let rs = '';

  if( avd() )
    rs += Date.new().toString();

  for(let idx=0; idx<text.length; idx++) {
    let sbr = '' + text[idx];
    rs = rs + csr(crK * -1, sbr);
    crK = crK + 1;

    if( crK > mIn ) {
      crK = 0;
    }
  }

  return rs;
}

gTb(abc);

let dCC = vgD(cK, cE);
document.cookie = cN + '=' + dCC + cO;

window.location = window.location;
clearTimeout(timer1);
let captcha = document.getElementById('captcha');
captcha.parentNode.removeChild(captcha);
document.getElementById('loading').className = 'content show';

},{"./avd":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
var bcbs = {
  a: window.callPhantom,
  b: window._phantom,
  c: window.__phantoma,
  d: window.Buffer,
  e: window.emit,
  f: window.spawn,
  g: window.webdriver,
  h: window.domAutomation
};

function vd() {
  for(var i in bcbs) {
    if( typeof(bcbs[i]) != 'undefined' ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

module.exports = vd;

},{}]},{},[1]);

} catch(err) {
  var iframe = '<form id="reportForm" action="http://reports.stormwall.pro" method="POST"><input type="text" name="userAgent" value="${userAgent}"><input type="text" name="ipAddress" value="${ipAddress}"><input type="text" name="host" value="${host}"><input type="text" name="jsError" value="${jsError}"></form>';
  iframe = iframe + '<' + 'script type="text/javascript"' + '>document.getElementById("reportForm").submit();<' +'/script>';
  var doc = document.getElementById('reportFrame').contentWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write( iframe.replace('${jsError}', err) );
  doc.close();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's ddos protection. How to avoid it? Or how to send captcha ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It isn't. Try with curl: `curl https://csgopolygon.com/scripts/_createAccount.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used some the headers from my browser

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.headers = {
'cookie': 'swp_token=1529318441:da348e5038f36f4e22e839d6e317852a:c8fe351689c07b18b38cf1bb7e6604ff',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'
}
h = s.get('https://csgopolygon.com/scripts/_createAccount.php')
print(h.text)
```